# Override equals() and hashCode() using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, hashcode

I wrote a utility method to override `equals()` using reflection. This works fine, but I wonder if this code will pass all the tests.

```
public static boolean checkObjectsEqualityFromInstance(Object currentObj,Object otherObj) throws Exception{
      if(currentObj==null || otherObj==null){
          return false;
      }
      else if(otherObj.getClass()!=null&&currentObj.getClass()!=null&&!currentObj.getClass().isInstance(otherObj)){
          return false;
      }
      boolean result =true;
        Field[] fields = otherObj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        Field[] currentObjFields = currentObj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        Map<String, Object> attriButeNameValueMap=null; /*This map to store *property name and its value of any of object in my calse the otherObj */
        try {
            attriButeNameValueMap=new HashMap<>();
            for (Field field : fields) {
                field.setAccessible(true); 

                Object value = field.get(otherObj);
                attriButeNameValueMap.put(field.getName(), value);
            }
            for (Field field : currentObjFields) {
                field.setAccessible(true); 

                Object value = field.get(currentObj);
                if(attriButeNameValueMap.containsKey(field.getName())){
                    if(value instanceof Boolean){
                result=areEqual((Boolean)value, (Boolean)attriButeNameValueMap.get(field.getName()));
                    }
                    else if(value instanceof Character){
                        result=result&&areEqual((Character)value, (Character)attriButeNameValueMap.get(field.getName()));
                            }
                    else if(value instanceof Long){
                        result=result&&areEqual((Long)value, (Long)attriButeNameValueMap.get(field.getName()));
                    }
                    else if(value instanceof Float){
                        result=result&&areEqual((Float)value, (Float)attriButeNameValueMap.get(field.getName()));
                    }
                    else if(value instanceof Double){
                        result=result&&areEqual((Double)value, (Double)attriButeNameValueMap.get(field.getName()));
                    }
                    else if(value instanceof Object[]){
                        result=result&&  Arrays.equals((Object[])value, (Object[])attriButeNameValueMap.get(field.getName()));
                    }
                    else{
                        result=result&&areEqual(value, attriButeNameValueMap.get(field.getName()));

                    }
                    if(!result){
                        return result;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
            }

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
throw e;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The `areEqual()` methods are overloaded for different types.

Comment: This code doesn't deal properly with fields that are arrays of primitives.

Comment: There is no need for a special case for box classes like `Boolean`, `Character`, `Double`... they can simply be treated the same as Object.

Comment: I agree thanks.... i am waiting for more comments so that i can remember points for future, when i code again :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. It ignores values in superclasses. You might want to check that too.

   Anyway, don't reinvent the weel, **there is a library for that!** I guess [`EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html#reflectionEquals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) does exactly what you want.  It also has solutions to corner cases, like

   - transient fields (since they are likely derived fields, and not part of the value of the Object) in a configurable way
   - [generated fields with `$` (for inner classes)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7484210/843804).

   You can also exclude field names from the comparison.

   It's open-source, you can check the [source for further details](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html#line.324).

   See also: *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 47: Know and use the libraries* (The author mentions only the JDK's built-in libraries but I think the reasoning could be true for other libraries too.)
2. The `else` keyword is unnecessary here:

   ```
   if(currentObj==null || otherObj==null){
       return false;
   }
   else if(otherObj.getClass()!=null&&currentObj.getClass()!=null&&!currentObj.getClass().isInstance(otherObj)){
       return false;
   }
   ```

   The following is the same:

   ```
   if (currentObj == null || otherObj == null){
       return false;
   }
   if (otherObj.getClass() != null && currentObj.getClass() != null && 
           !currentObj.getClass().isInstance(otherObj)) {
       return false;
   }
   ```

   It's called [guard clause](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/). I've also used a little bit more spacing to make it readable (easier separaton of values, comparisons, method calls).
3. Guard clauses would make this easier to follow too:

   > ```
   >   if(value instanceof Boolean){
   >       result=areEqual((Boolean)value, (Boolean)attriButeNameValueMap.get(field.getName()));
   >   }
   >   else if(value instanceof Character){
   >       result=result&&areEqual((Character)value, (Character)attriButeNameValueMap.get(field.getName()));
   >   }
   >   else if(value instanceof Long){
   >       result=result&&areEqual((Long)value, (Long)attriButeNameValueMap.get(field.getName()));
   >   }
   >   ...
   >   if(!result){
   >       return result;
   >   }
   > ```

   I've used a few exaplanatory variable to remove some duplication:

   ```
   Object value = field.get(currentObj);
   String fieldName = field.getName();
   if(attriButeNameValueMap.containsKey(fieldName)){
         Object otherFieldValue = attriButeNameValueMap.get(fieldName);
         if (value instanceof Boolean) {
             if (!areEqual((Boolean) value, (Boolean) otherFieldValue)) {
                 return false;
             }
         } 
         if (value instanceof Character) {
             if (!areEqual((Character) value, (Character) otherFieldValue)) {
                 return false;
             }
         }
   ```

   Note that it makes superfluous the `result` variable. The last line of the method could be simply the following, since its never modified anymore:

   > ```
   > return true;
   > ```
4. Formatting is not consistent. Indentation sometimes is two spaces, sometimes four.
5. > ```
   >   Map<String, Object> attriButeNameValueMap=null; 
   >   /*This map to store *property name and its value of any of object in my calse the otherObj */
   >   try {
   >       attriButeNameValueMap=new HashMap<>();
   > ```

   `B` should be lowercase in the variable name (I guess it's just a typo) and you could declare it inside the `try` block:

   I'd also rename it to `otherObjectAttributeValues` to make the comment unnecessary:

   ```
   try {
       Map<String, Object> otherObjectAttributeValues = new HashMap<>();
   ```

   (*Effective Java, Second Edition, Item 45: Minimize the scope of local variables*)
6. Consistent formatting would be great here too:

   > ```
   >           } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
   >               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   >               e.printStackTrace();
   >   throw e;
   >           }
   > ```

   Furthermore, `TODO` comments does not suggest professional work. Fix that and remove the comment.

   I'd throw out the `IllegalAccessException` or wrap it into a `RuntimeException`. The IllegalArgumentException already a `RuntimeException`, so you don't have to put it into the method signature.

Comment: I really liked the way you reviewed my code and commented on each mistake.This was nice experience for me on this site ... :) thanks bro.

Comment: @khushnood: You're welcome! I'm happy that you found it helpful :)

Comment: @khushnood: One more thing: If you like the site help [graduating](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1572/7076). I'm quite sure that you can find other useful questions and answers on the site to [vote on](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/612/7076).

Answer (score 7):

1. You should check if the references are equal first to save a whole lot of comparing when there is no need to.
2. If both objects are `null` your method will return false which is probably unexpected.
3. You call `getClass()` several times on these objects - It should only be called once for each object and then stored in a local variable.
4. There is a typo in `attriButeNameValueMap` - should be `attributeNameValueMap`
5. You call `field.getName()` several times - again just call once per loop and store in a local variable.